Socket is not defined - node.js and socket.io
I'm creating a Chat App by node.js and socket.io.
Everything worked fine and the socket variable has been defined so far by the engine well - The socket variable was declared in the index.html file inside the <script> tags as it was guided by socket.io.
However, once I added this line of code to the index.js, the engine started telling me that "socket is not defined". Line of code:
if (!socket.recovered) {
    // if the connection state recovery was not successful
    try {
      await db.each('SELECT id, content FROM messages WHERE id > ?',
        [socket.handshake.auth.serverOffset || 0],
        (_err, row) => {
          socket.emit('chat message', row.content, row.id);
        }
      )
    } catch (e) {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }

I tried to recheck all the codes and socket's documentation repeatedly, but I can't figure out why it keeps happening.
Here are the codes:
index.js file:
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join } from 'node:path';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import {open} from "sqlite";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    connectionStateRecovery: {}
  });

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));


//Opening database file
const db = await open({
    filename: "chat.db",
    driver: sqlite3.Database
});

await db.exec(`
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      client_offset TEXT UNIQUE,
      content TEXT
  );
`);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});


//The route that handles the messages and emit them
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");
    socket.on('chat message', async (msg, clientOffset, callback) => {
        let result;
        try {
            result = await db.run('INSERT INTO messages (content, client_offset) VALUES (?, ?)', msg, clientOffset);
        } catch (e) {
            if (e.errno === 19 /* SQLITE_CONSTRAINT */ ) {
                // the message was already inserted, so we notify the client
                callback();
              } else {
                // nothing to do, just let the client retry
              }
              return;
        }
        
        io.emit("chat message", msg, result.lastID);
        console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
        callback();
    });
});

if (!socket.recovered) {
    // if the connection state recovery was not successful
    try {
      await db.each('SELECT id, content FROM messages WHERE id > ?',
        [socket.handshake.auth.serverOffset || 0],
        (_err, row) => {
          socket.emit('chat message', row.content, row.id);
        }
      )
    } catch (e) {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
});

index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>



    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
let counter = 0;

const socket = io({
        ackTimeout: 10000,
        retries: 3,
        auth: {
          serverOffset: 0
        }
      });

  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  const messages = document.getElementById('messages');

    
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (input.value) {
      const clientOffset = `${socket.id}-${counter++}`;
      socket.emit('chat message', input.value, clientOffset);
      input.value = '';
    }
  });
    
socket.on('chat message', (msg, serverOffset) => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = msg;
    messages.appendChild(item);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    socket.auth.serverOffset = serverOffset;
  });

</script>
  </body>
</html>


Your if (!socket.recovered) { is outside of  io.on("connection", async (socket) => { and socket doesn't exist there
